# Installation failed: Destination folder already exists

Tags: installation

I was sure I had installed Wordfence Security plug-in but it's not there, it says "You do not appear to have any plugins available at this time". So I went to install it but i get this message "Installation failed: Destination folder already exists".   Advice please - I am a complete beginner by the way!

Comment: My best advice would be: don’t install Wordfence (it won’t help you with anything and will be harmful for performance of your site). Harden your site in proper way instead - you’ll be much safer.

Comment: you can check the plugins folder via ftp.